# How do I get messages to embedded dialogs in MFC?

Tags: mfc, windows-messages

I seem to have the original problem from [Embedded Modeless Child Dialog not getting messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239419/embedded-modeless-child-dialog-not-getting-messages). I have managed to add rows to my property page using tips form [What is the best way to manage data for rows of similar controls in MFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903137/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-data-for-rows-of-similar-controls-in-mfc) but now when I click on the controls in the embedded dialog, nothing happens.  I assume there's some message routing I need to do in the parent dialog but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The properties of the row dialog resource included Disabled = True.  I have no idea how that happened.